# [eclipse]I want to add another move for my button in the timer

Tags: java, javascript, android, eclipse, timer

guys I am new to the eclipse, I am practicing the timer in eclipse, can I have some help for my codes?
The code below is like if I clicked the trigger button while it is counting, it will trigger another counting without stop the previous counting.

I have tried chancel the button or reactive it after the down counting, still i want to know how to make the same trigger button acquire the restart counting function. Can u help me by directly embed to my code please? I know i am too new to eclipse, java even eng, everything, i would need your explanation if it is not going to take your take too much.

```
Button countDownButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.countDown1);      
countDownButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view){

          CountDownTimer timer2 = new CountDownTimer(3000,1000){

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {

                    mTimeLabel1.setText("Times Up baby!");
                }

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {                               

                      int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                      int minutes = seconds / 60;
                      seconds = seconds % 60;

                      mTimeLabel1.setText("" + minutes + ":"
                                                      + String.format("%02d", seconds));

                }          
          }.start();

    }
});
```

Comment: Please can you try to structure your question a little bit better? I am finding it very hard to understand exactly what you are wanting to happen when you press the button.

Comment: yes sir, it was something like first time i press the button, counting view started

Comment: however, if i press the trigger button again during the counting, it will trigger another counting without stopping the previous counting

Comment: i want to render it like if i press the button again during the counting, i can restart the counting, on the same button

Comment: @NutterzUK my lord, may i seek help from you /_\

Comment: Can you send me the whole working project so I can take a look? Maybe upload a zip somewhere.

Comment: sure sir, but i made some changes on the code from above now, i will upload asap and tell if it is ready

Comment: Try my solution first, see if it works.(posting answer now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current solution is creating an new countdowntimer but not stopping the old one. Therefore if you click the button again you have 2 countdown timers. When you say "new CountDowntimer", that is when you create it. Therefore, before you create a new one, make sure to stop the previous one.

```
    Button countDownButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.countDown1);      
    countDownButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  

    CountDownTimer timer2;
    public void onClick(View view){

          if(timer2!=null){
              timer2.cancel();
          }
          timer2 = new CountDownTimer(3000,1000){

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {

                    mTimeLabel1.setText("Times Up baby!");
                }

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {                               

                      int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                      int minutes = seconds / 60;
                      seconds = seconds % 60;

                      mTimeLabel1.setText("" + minutes + ":"
                                                      + String.format("%02d", seconds));

                }          
          }.start();

    }
});
```

**Explanation**

Previously, each time you clicked the button you had a new CountDownTimer. Each countdown timer was changing the value of the label mTimeLabel1. The new timer is created because inside your on click lister, you were doing this:

```
CountdownTimer2 timer2 = new CountDownTimer(3000,1000)
```

This means, create a new Timer, and keep a reference to it called timer2. After the onClick method is finished, the timer keeps running. However, when you click again you create a new timer and a new reference to the old timer is lost. The reference is not to the old one but to the new one.

So, instead we make sure that the click listener has only one timer. To do this we move the reference to it outside of the onClick method so that we can keep the reference to the timer. We can then make sure that we check this timer to cancel it before starting another one.  However, if it is the first time that you have clicked on the button then the timer will be null, because "new CountdownTimer" hasn't yet been called. So, we check that it is not null (it's not the first button press), and if it is not then cancel the old one before creating a new one. If it is the first button press, we don't want to call cancel because there is no timer to cancel.

Comment: I haven't tested this as I don't have the whole project, but it should work.

Comment: it works.....................how come

Comment: Ok, let me add an explanation to the main answer, one mo.

Comment: i am too new to this, this is amazing,
          if(timer2!=null){
              timer2.cancel();
         i am not sure what (timer2!=null) means, it means? if timer2 is exists, timer2 need to be chanceled?

Comment: hmm i want to know what if i still ask it to cancel even it is the first time pressing? will it render the whole apps crumble?

Comment: anyway i love you sir, great help there

Comment: If you ask it to cancel the first time you press it, it will try to call the cancel() method on a timer which doesn't exist (null). Therefore you will get a NullPointerException.

Comment: if(timer2!=null){ timer2.cancel(); 

It means that if you click on the button, it will check if the timer is already on. if the timer is counting, it will not be null, and therefore it will cancel the timer.